# VNC on elementary os

Tags: vnc, elementary-os

I installed elementary OS on my laptop and tried to install VNC server. First I installed `vnc4server`, opened and logged from phone. On screen I saw:

```
failed to load session gnome
```

How do I need to configure it to run under elementary OS? I am not interested in installing GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file named .xsession in your home directory and write the following content into it.

```
 gnome-session --session=pantheon
```

Then restart the vncserver and connect again. I tested this with tightvncserver.

---

If you want to use display:0 use x11vnc. [Here you can find more information](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/tightvncserver-show-the-same-screen-on-hdmi-and-vncclient) about how to setup and connect to a x11vnc server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `x11vnc` via apt (or *X11VNC Server* application from AppCenter in EOS 5 or earlier).
2. Run:

```
sudo x11vnc -storepasswd # This will prompt password, confirmation and the location, choose `/home/your-user/.vnc`.
```

3. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` with the following commands:

```
[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /home/your-user/.vnc/passwd
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4. Make the systemd get the changes:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service
sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
```

Done. This should allow you to hook into existing session or start a new one.

Tested with:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
Release:    5.1.7
Codename:   hera
```

And:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Elementary
Description:    elementary OS 7 Horus
Release:    7
Codename:   horus
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)